# Get data from $resource response in angular factory

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have this factory:

```
.factory("Member", function($resource) {
    var endpoint = "http://some valid url";

    function generateMemberToken (id1, id2) {
        return $resource(endpoint, null, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'id1': id1,
                    'id2': id2
                }
            }
        })
    }

    var member = {
        generateMemberToken : generateMemberToken
    }

    return member;
})
```

and this controller:

```
 .controller('memberKeyCtrl', function($scope, Member){

    $scope.generateMemberToken = function () {
        $scope.member = Member.generateMemberToken('123456789', '789456123').query();
        console.log($scope.member);
        console.log($scope.member.someProperty); // problem here
    }
```

$scope.member is a JSON response from an API, i.e.

```
 {firstName:Joe, lastName:smith}
```

I can see my ouput in the console for "$scope.member" and it has the property im looking for here, referred to as .someProperty.   I just cannot seem to extract that data as i have it here, see the "//problem here" line in the controller.

My guess is that I somehow set up my factory incorrectly or am not making the property somehow available outside of the factory.  New to angular so having some trouble understanding this.

Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Comment: what's in `$scope.member` ?

Comment: a few properties, i.e. first name, last name, my question in general is, how do i get properties out of that?  The properties are simple key/value responses.  member is a json response returned from an API.

Comment: should add, there is no root object in that member, added to the post for more info.

Comment: what does this output? `$scope.member.$promise['finally'](console.log.bind(console));`

Comment: $state: Object
status: 1
value: e
$promise: d
$resolved: true
dob: null
encryptedMemberId: "some value"
firstName: null
lastName: null
middleName: null
relationToSubscriber: null
__proto__: e
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: weirdest thing, i can output to a page with {{member.firstName}}, but cannot log to the console or assign to a variable

Comment: `$resource` is returning a `promise`. You have to pass a callback to access the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is with the Async nature of $resource, and how the console interacts with your data.

`.query()` is an asynchronous call, which means that it does not return a value immediately; instead it allows the code to continue to flow.  Your next statement is to `console.log($scope.member);`, which doesn't immediately expand `$scope.member` to see it's properties until they are used or inspected.  The next call is to `console.log($scope.member.someProperty);`, which **would** expand `$scope.member` in order to find `someProperty`.   Since the callback to your `.query()` hasn't returned yet, this is going to log `undefined`.  By the time you go to check to see what is in the *first* `console.log`, the callback has completed, and so the object appears as though it had all the properties all along, even though it didn't really, at the time they were attempted to be accessed.

The simple way to handle this is to wrap the calls in `.then()`, to ensure that you aren't executing them until after the promise from `.query()` has returned.  In order to chain `.then()`, you need to access the promise returned, i.e.

```
$scope.generateMemberToken = function () {
    $scope.member = Member.generateMemberToken('123456789', '789456123')
    .query().$promise.then(function(){
        console.log($scope.member);
        console.log($scope.member.someProperty); // problem here
    });
};
```

The `.query()` function syntax allows for an anonymous callback, that will allow you to pass a function that should be executed when the `query()` is complete, rather than chaining `.then()` statements.  For example:

```
 $scope.generateMemberToken = function () {
    $scope.member = Member.generateMemberToken('123456789', '789456123')
    .query({}, function() {
        console.log($scope.member);
        console.log($scope.member.someProperty); // problem here
    });
}
```

Comment: this makes complete sense, but not sure .Then fixes the problem, i get this in the console "TypeError: Member.generateMemberToken(...).query(...).Then is not a function", also tried with lowercase .then

Comment: also thank you for the very clear explanation of whats happening

Comment: hmm, there still seems to be something off with your calling syntax here, give me a few moments to work through the logic and update the code a bit.

Comment: very much appreciated

Comment: just some feedback, the second solution fit my immediate needs, but i think i need the first solution if i want an easy way to handle errors that could happen.